# How to cache many images(in loop) properly using forge.file.cacheURL?

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I have a list of products that I download as json file from server. Each item contains a link to the image stored on server.

Now I want to be able to see the products when offline, so I store downloaded json file into forge.prefs http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/prefs.html and pull it out to display items on screen. It works nice but I also need to store images localy to be displayed correctly.

To achive this, I'm trying to use forge.file.cacheURL http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/features/cache.html but can't handle the correct order of operations. To cache images I run the json file and for each line I call forge.file.cacheURL and store the url back to JSON item. But here is the problem as forge.file.cacheURL runs asynchronously so my loop running over the items and gathering the local images finishes and my code continues to display images(view items) but meantime the forge.file.cacheURL still gathers and caches the images because its asynchronous operation. I need somehow to detect that last item is being cached and then refresh the view on screen to use correct image urls ... or something else that will lead to what I need.

Hopefully you understand the concept. How should I handle this properly ?

Comment: Could you share a code snippet which demonstrates the problem? Not quite sure I follow!

Comment: The answer might involve a long answer.  The images are somewhat cached in the "browser".  Are you using backbone.js?

Comment: I know that the browser caches the images, the problem occures if system removes your app from memory and the entire browser cache is removed. forge.pref can survive this what is great ...

Answer (score 0):

Since v1.4.26 you've been able to permanently store images (see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-26), rather than just cache them. Depending on your needs, that might be a better option than `forge.file.cacheURL` and `forge.file.isFile`.

I don't follow exactly the situation you describe, but something like this will let you wait for several asynchronous things to finish before doing something:

```
// e.g.
var jsonCache = {
    one: "http://example.com/one.jpg",
    two: "http://example.com/two.jpg",
    three: "http://example.com/three.jpg"
};

var cacheCount = 0;
for (var name in jsonCache) {
    if (jsonCache.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        var imageURL = jsonCache[name];
        cacheCount += 1;
        forge.file.cacheURL(imageURL, function (file) {
            forge.prefs.set(name, file, function () {
                cacheCount -= 1; // race condition, but should be fine (!)
                if (cacheCount <= 0) {
                    alert('all cached');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```